# read all option in another page

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a form which sends information with post method to another page. In the form I have a select box with three options, for example:

```
<select name="slctstate" id="slctstate">
      <option value="0">aaaaa</option>
      <option value="1">bbbbb</option>
      <option value="2">ccccc</option>
</select>
```

In another page, I read the selected item with `$_POST['slctstate']`, but I want to read all `options (key & value)` in the select tag. 
Can I do this?

Comment: you could use multi select box ?

Comment: (Sorry for the weird [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/25441857/revisions), another edit was made as I was editing.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First use a jquery function which stores all the options in a string

```
$(document).ready(function()
                   {
                      var myoption = '';
                      $('#drop_down option').each(function() 
                        {
                             myoption = myoption + ',' + ($(this).val());
                        });
                      $('#hidden_text').val(myoption);
                   }
                 );
```

in the html use a hidden field

```
<input type="hidden" id="hidden_text" name="hidden_text"/>
```

WHen you will submit the form, catch this value with a list of options separated by (,);

On the action page, you can split the value using php explode() function

Check the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/1u9x5nbq/3/

Comment: Want to know about the idiot who downvoted it just a couple of moments before... Trying to help people, and some guys are just giving negative points. Now don't anybody dare to say that this way it doesn't work.. See the fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't without a work-around. The only value gets passed is the selected value. If you want to know all values you can use a work-around in javascript e.g.:

```
<select name="slctstate" id="slctstate">
    <option value="0">aaaaa</option>
    <option value="1">bbbbb</option>
    <option value="2">ccccc</option>
</select>

//Include JQuery
<script>
    $(function()
    {
        $('#slctstate option').each(function()
        {
            $('#slctstate').after('<input type="text" value="'+$(this).text()+'" name="slctstateOptions['+$(this).val()+']" style="display:none;" />');
            //Where val() is the key and text() is the value.
        });
    });
</script>
```

Then you can access the values by using `$_POST['slctstateOptions']`.

Answer (score -1):

No, you can't do that from the form. When you do submit, you send only selected value(s).

Answer (score -1):

No, 
The only value that is "selected" will be POSTed on Submit.